# SQL- two date columns in one table to find the busiest minute

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an application database, and this table has a timestamp when there is a process that occurs. There are two columns start_time and complete_time that shows entries on the table for any process.

Now there are alot of same timestamp for both start_time and same complete_time together, and I am trying to find how many processes occurred during that minute for both start and complete_time. I do not know how to combine start_time with complete_time that will show me how many entries occured that minute. I only can show start_time for now. This will help us to see at the application side when was the heaviest load. Thanks for your time.

```
WITH mainQuery
as (select TO_CHAR(start_time, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI') AS start_date, id from LOG_TABLE)
SELECT start_date, COUNT (id) as ProcessCount
FROM mainQuery
GROUP BY start_date
order by ProcessCount desc
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_CHAR(start_time, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI') AS start_date, count(*) from LOG_TABLE where TO_CHAR(start_time, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI') in
(select TO_CHAR(start_time, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI') from LOG_TABLE
where TO_CHAR(start_time, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI') = TO_CHAR(complete_time, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI'))
group by start_date;
```

Is this you want.
Take all the start time with start time = complete time, then take the count of those rows from the main table.